# IntelliJ won't accept Java8 and diamonds at the end of List/Map

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea, ide

I'm using the latest JDK and everywhere from project creation to now everything is set to Java8 or SDK 8.

Still, intelliJ gives me this issue:

[image]

The red lamp tells me to change to Java7.

This is my project settings:
[image]

and this is the Modules section:
[image]

As you can see; I specifically changed it from the SDK default to java 8 when I got the error, but no result.

The compiler settings look like this:
[image]

I'm on a macbook and the intelliJ is the community version. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I fix it?

Comment: Try clearing caches. CTRL+SHIFT+A >> "Cache" >> Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Comment: It's in the File menu as well.

Comment: Invalidate caches, restart.

Comment: I tried doing that, twice, issue persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to run the project, if this is your error message:
[image]

Then I suggest you have a little look into your `pom`-file.

This project was built using the intelliJ maven project setting, and it was missing this lovely line of code:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

IntelliJ doesn't (at least in my case) generate the version in the pom (despite that I picked all the settings for it).

Answer (score 0):

I tried specifying the compiler version in the plugin too, to no avail. Have you tried invalidating the cache? It's `File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart...`. I would probably restart as well for good measure.

Comment: Yes, I did try it and it didn't work for me, however it may work for someone else.

Comment: I got into a similar state on IDEA 14 for Mac and never solved it. I ended up recreating my work in a new repository. I think the initial problem was that I created a Spring project via Maven archetype generator and then I messed up the addition of the `pom.xml` file. I was never able to recover.